# Wordpress - if is_plugin function?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

So, I have been trying a couple of things but I can't figure it out.

In my header.php file I have a simple PHP line (custom-made Wordpress theme):

```
<?php if ( is_page('Home') || is_404() ||  is_search() ) { echo ""; } else { echo "<h1>". get_the_title() ."</h1>"; } ?>
```

This was working GREAT until I was required to install "The Events Calendar" plugin and adapt it to my theme.

The plugin allows me to go into its settings and create a URL slug, in this case I named it "reunions" and I did "reunion" slug for single events. So, logically I should be able to do this:

```
<?php if ( is_page('Home') || is_page('reunions') || is_page('reunion') || is_404() ||  is_search() ) { echo ""; } else { echo "<h1>". get_the_title() ."</h1>"; } ?>
```

But this didn't work, additionally I tried these two things but no luck:

$pagenow == 'the-events-calendar.php'

is_plugin_active( 'the-events-calendar/the-events-calendar.php' )

My work around would be to manually add `<h1>(title)</h1>` to each page, there's gotta be a way to do this. Is it possible to create a is_plugin('the-events-calendar') function to check for the plugin and disable the H1 line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Quick question - is your front page just an archive of all your blog posts, or is it an normal website front page (not sure if that makes sense?)

Comment: makes sense, front page is a regular page - blog posts are "news" posts on another part of the site.

Comment: And I'm assuming that the `"<h1>". get_the_title() ."</h1>"` is not supposed to show on the front page?

Comment: correct, front page has a video and other elements that do not require H1 tags

Comment: Oh wait I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. Apologies. Gimme a minute :)

Comment: ok in this case is_front_page() is the same as is_page('Home'), this works as intended on those pages. but if the user is on the plugin page the H1 tags are displayed hence why I tried is_page('reunions') and is_page('reunion') as these are the slugs of the plugin. i need to avoid H1 tags to echo when the user is on the plug-in's page, example: http://example.com/reunions/ and/or http://example.com/reunion/

Comment: Like I said, I misunderstood the question originally, but user8230352 has got the right answer below. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [is_singular()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) function to check if the current post is of plugin's event custom post type, like this:

```
<?php if ( is_page('Home') || is_singular('tribe_events')...
```

**Update:**

You could also use [has_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function, to check for specific slug, like this:

```
<?php if ( is_page('Home') || has_term('reunions')...
```

Comment: Ok great, this works when the user is looking at a specific event http://example.com/reunion/event-title-here but when the user is on the main page of the plugin the H1 tags are populated (problematically) http://example.com/reunions/

Comment: Maybe you must add this **is_post_type_archive( 'tribe_events' )** https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive

Comment: has_term didn't work but due to your help this was key and worked: <?php if ( is_front_page() || is_404() ||  is_search() || is_post_type_archive('tribe_events') || is_singular('tribe_events') ) { echo ""; } else { echo "<h1>". get_the_title() ."</h1>"; } ?>